# can't find fbxImporter XNA

Tags: xna

i've reinstalled xna and when i tried to run a game that worked fine on the old xna, i got "can't find fbxImporter". Any ideas why ?

Regards,
Alexandru Badescu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Content References.  You may find that the Reference is there, but has an exclamation mark against it.  Simply remove the Reference, then add a new Reference and you'll be able to find it in the .Net list.

**EDIT**

As you have said you had an old XNA project, I'm thinking that you may now have a few of these exclamation marks against all of the Microsoft.Xna.Framework references.  This is because they are pointing to the old framework and you are now using the new framework.